# missing \maketitle in cls file (gsag3jnl)

Tags: errors, overleaf

I want to use this template (https://github.com/kbroman/GSATemplate), there is a .tex file inside, and I got the following errors:

[image: CLS_error]

I tried with other answers that I saw in other questions and didn't succeed (like changing the format, just UTF-8  without BOM, and nothing happens...) :(

EDIT1:

[image]

\bibliography not working!!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE --- can you amend your question with some (ideally minimal) code that gives these errors?

Comment: I would write who ever is maintaining that template and ask them to update it. If you get no rely then don't use that template. It seems to have been written by overleaf so perhaps contact overleaf support. It is not really our job to debug a broken template.

Comment: @chsk in the github repo there is a tex. example, that is what I am trying to run

Comment: Completely random guess: maybe move the abstract below `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Hi, Tom from Overleaf here. The templates themselves seem to be OK, see the links in my answer. If that GitHub repo is providing some bad files, this might be worth opening an issue there.

Comment: Remove alle instances of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` from the `.cls`. Apparently the file have been editoed by someone who did not know what they were doing. If you look in the versions provided by OverLeaf (see yo's answer) you'll see what these macro are not present (as they are irrelevant inside a cls). Now you know why we tend to not recommend using random templates from the internet. They often have errors or bad design.

Comment: Thanks @daleif for the findings, I've filed an issue at the GH repo.

Answer (score 2):

(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)

The Github repo you mention at https://github.com/kbroman/GSATemplate links to the original templates at Overleaf:

- https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-preparing-your-submission-to-genetics-using-overleaf/stmpddtqcxtx
- https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-preparing-your-submission-to-g3-genes-genomes-genetics-using-overleaf/vffkrpmjrcgf

These templates work correctly with our latest TeX Live 2020 compiler, as you can try yourself.

I'm not sure what's wrong with the templates in the GitHub repo, but you can probably ask its owner. (Overleaf does not own, create or maintain the GitHub repo obviously.)

Comment: It's `\makeatother` inside the cls, when it comes to `\renewcommand{\@maketitle}` `@` is no longer a letter and interesting things happen

Comment: @daleif Good catch. The versions in the Overleaf Gallery are corrected, but the GH repo didn't catch up.

Comment: @daleif Thanks, I've now filed an issue to the GH repo.

Comment: It the repo owner the original maker of this or just someone who copied it?

Comment: @daleif I believe this was done inside Overleaf, but I'm unable to say 100%.

Comment: @daleif So yes, this originates in Overleaf or it's based on some very old templates for the journals. Either way, it's been maintained by Overleaf for quite some time (several years at least).

Comment: @yo' The template from overleaf works perfectly, thanks! I have another question, the template does not print the bibliography! I attach a screenshot to the post (see EDIT1)